# Can I use .getpoint for select position for top of cone

Tags: vba, autocad

I use this code for get point and a point that I select is the base of cone But I need to use a selected point to be a top of my cone that is drawing then.

```
conecenter = .GetPoint(, vbCr & "select position for base of cone:")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the `.getpoint` method merely prompts the user to specify an arbitrary point, either by selecting the point graphically, or entering the point coordinate values at the AutoCAD command line. As such, the user may specify any point in the current viewport.

To calculate the top of the cone, you will need to decrease the z-coordinate of the user-supplied point `conecenter` by half the cone height, e.g.:

```vb
conecenter(2) = conecenter(2) - coneheight / 2.0
```

This assumes that you have a variable called `coneheight` which represents the height of the cone.

Comment: so sorry but I 've edited my post can you answer me  in a correct question
Thank you